# Are sheep permanently dyed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If you shear a sheep that is dyed, will it re-grow wool with the color it was dyed with, or will it turn back to white?

Comment: Do not shorn sheep stay shorn until death or despawn?

Comment: @Raven - nice tongue twister you've got there!

Comment: I've never seen a shorn sheep respawn wool. I usually shear them too hard, stupid diamond sword.

Comment: I suppose the first part of the question should be "does a shorn sheep regrow it's wool?".

Comment: They did in one of the earlier modes (survival? maybe?) But I don't think they do in Alpha/Beta.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes.**

I dyed a sheep orange,

[image]

sheared it,

[image]

and it regrew orange wool.

[image]

Comment: This is a new behavior as of the 1.1 update (http://mojang.com/2012/01/12/minecraft-1-1-update/) which was released on 1/12/12.

Comment: Sheep is simply enjoying the scenery, so peaceful.

Comment: As a historical note, sheep retained their colour in 1.0.0 when shorn. Although they couldn't regrow their wool in that version, you could breed two shorn sheep, and their offspring would be the same colour as the parents.

Answer (score 7):

> **This answer is outdated as of the Minecraft 1.1 Patch**

<s>**No.**</s>

Because sheep cannot regrow their fur, they have no chance of being "permanently dyed."

Comment: Because sheep cannot regrow their wool, it is *undeterminable* as to whether they remain permanently dyed.

Comment: I don't think that warranted a correction.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate as of 1.1.

Comment: While it is no longer accurate, I think that striking the entire answer through is unnecessary, and that the note at the top is quite enough.