# As of 1.8, do sheep regrow their wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do shorn sheep regrow their wool?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/do-shorn-sheep-regrow-their-wool)

On a previous version of minecraft I used to be able to dye sheep and they'd regrow their wool providing I didn't get too far from them. Now, they don't appear to regrow their wool. Is this true?

Also, do they still spawn in 1.8? They seem pretty rare around my town....

Comment: Well theres definitely no lack of pigs in 1.8...

Comment: [Shorn sheep haven't regrown their wool for a while](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/do-shorn-sheep-regrow-their-wool). What you might have seen is the effect of shorn sheep de-spawning and then respawning with a new coat.

Comment: @ChrisF It's been a while since I played, but I'm fairly sure it was regrowing since I would dye the sheep colors that are not natural and sheer the colored wool regularly

Comment: I've killed off all the local animals, and have *yet* to see any respawning :( Since passive mobs don't require grass to respawn any more, it's possible they're stuck in a cave somewhere...

Comment: @Cyclops they can't be stuck in a cave, they always spawn at the highest available (opaque?) level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they do not. Notch tested sheep regrowth but then removed it some time ago. It is planned for the future though, because animals are now persistent. [Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep), [Source 2](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Sheep#Information_about_regrowing_wool.3F), [Source 3](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool_Dyes).

Comment: I saw reference to a mod that regrows Sheep Wool - Do you know if that's still around and what it's called?

Comment: A quick glance at `EntitySheep.java` appears to confirm this.

Comment: @Rachel The [Domestic Animals mod](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/domestic-animals-plus/) does that.

Comment: @John Thanks, but that mod currently doesn't work for 1.8 and it looks like there's no plans on fixing it until 1.9. Still, looks like a cool mod :)

Comment: @Rachel [There is an easy way to keep multiple versions installed.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29272/how-do-i-keep-two-different-versions-of-minecraft-installed/30123#30123)