# Do sheep regrow their wool in Minecraft 1.0?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do shorn sheep regrow their wool?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15238/do-shorn-sheep-regrow-their-wool)

Various versions of Minecraft either added or removed the ability for sheep to regrow their wool when shorn. Does this occur in Minecraft 1.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of Minecraft 1.0, sheep do not regrow wool. As stated in [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sheep), this was added in the newest test version, which is called Week 49 Snapshot. In that test version, sheep eat the grass off of dirt blocks and regrow their wool when that happens.