# How can I convince my sheep to regrow their wool?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft 1.1 is out now, and sheep once again regrow their wool by eating grass.

I've got a sizeable herd of blue-colored sheep I'd like to farm wool from - is there anything I can do to make it more likely that they will eat grass and regrow their wool? Is there a cooldown period between eating?

Comment: Dyed sheep stay dyed when they regrow their hair?  That's not how it works IRL...

Comment: @NickT - And? Minecraft != IRL

Comment: @NickT - Yes, they do.  Now.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15231/are-sheep-permanently-dyed

Comment: You could always increase your sheep herd by breeding them, allowing you to mitigate the effects of an eating timeout (currently unknown as of this answer.) Breeding timeout is 5 minutes, so I'd assume eating timeout would be similar.

Comment: Have you left fashion magazines lying around in an attempt to induce body shame?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have a small corral full of colored sheep, probably 20-30. If I run around holding a pair of shears while holding RMB, I cannot keep all of the sheep sheared as they are eating that fast. Sheep seem to eat even if they are uninjured and have wool, but perhaps the 1.1 patch caused fishing rods to damage passive mobs.

So the answer is "I don't think you have to do anything, except expand your flock."

Do not hold wheat in your hand around the sheep - they will swarm you and ignore the grass.

Sheep will also eat tall grass, which you can add to your pasture by using bonemeal. It also has the pleasant side effect of giving you flowers for the renewable dyes.